# How to convert XMLTYPE in VARCHAR in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

I have two columns in my table(TRANSACTION) in ORACLE which are XMLTYPE(XML_IN and XML_OUT). My procedure is not working because I don't know how to convert them to VARCHAR or something(I just think that this is the error). My procedure is:

```
PROCEDURE SEARCH_XML
(
    P_ID_TRANSACTION IN TRANSACTION.ID_TRANSACTION%TYPE,

    P_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN

    OPEN P_CURSOR FOR

    SELECT T.XML_IN, T.XML_OUT
    FROM TRANSACTION T
    WHERE T.ID_TRANSACTION = P_ID_TRANSACTION;

END SEARCH_XML;
```

When I call this procedure error message in VisualStudio2008 is: "Unsupported oracle data type USERDEFINED encountered." Any idea how is this working?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`XMLType`](https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14258_02/t_xml.htm) has two methods: `getStringVal()` and `getClobVal()` which will convert the XML structure to their string representations (as a `VARCHAR2` and `CLOB` respectively). Unless you know that your XML output is going to always be less than 4000 characters (bytes) then you will probably want to use `getClobVal()` like this:

```
PROCEDURE SEARCH_XML
(
    P_ID_TRANSACTION IN TRANSACTION.ID_TRANSACTION%TYPE,

    P_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT T.XML_IN.getClobVal() AS XML_IN,
           T.XML_OUT.getClobVal() AS XML_OUT
    FROM TRANSACTION T
    WHERE T.ID_TRANSACTION = P_ID_TRANSACTION;
END SEARCH_XML;
```