# Get value from table oracle (xmltype)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, toad

How can i get xml data from a table,

```sql
CREATE TABLE PCRD_3DS_SOAP_LOGS
(
  SERVICE_NAME  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  REQUEST_ID    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  ERROR_CODE    CHAR(5 BYTE),
  REQUEST       SYS.XMLTYPE,
  RESPONSE      SYS.XMLTYPE,
  USER_CREATE   VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  DATE_CREATE   DATE,
  USER_MODIF    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  DATE_MODIF    DATE
)
```

I get this error when I execute the select query:

```sql
select * from PCRD_3DS_SOAP_LOGS
```

> ```
> Access violation at address 659A0C4B in module 'OraClient12.Dll'. Read of address 00000008
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * FROM PCRD_3DS_SOAP_LOGS;
```

Should work, however, if Toad cannot handle the `XMLTYPE` data type then you can explicitly convert them to a string using [`XMLTYPE`'s `getStringVal` or `getClobVal` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039900/1509264):

```sql
SELECT service_name,
       request_id,
       error_code,
       p.request.getClobVal() AS request,
       p.response.getClobVal() AS response,
       user_create,
       date_create,
       user_modif,
       date_modif
FROM   PCRD_3DS_SOAP_LOGS p;
```

*(You do need to include the table name or alias before the column name.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ef015836a36dee2a011539fe84b291ee)*