# Fetch xml from xmltype in oracle

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I have a table in which there is a column of xmltype. I want to fetch the data in xml format for every row. I am not aware of the tags used in xml content.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your table(s); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the expected output for that sample output; a complete description of how you get from the sample data to the output; and **YOUR** attempt at a solution.

Comment: If you just want to convert the `XMLTYPE` back to a string then this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35039363/1509264

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are asking for every XML fragment in the document. You can use:

```sql
SELECT x.value
FROM   TABLE_NAME t
       CROSS JOIN
       xmltable(
         '//*'
         passing t.xml
         COLUMNS
           value XMLTYPE path '.'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<root><a>Value A</a><b>Value B</b><c><d>Value D</d><e><f>Value F</f></e></c></root>' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | <root><a>Value A</a><b>Value B</b><c><d>Value D</d><e><f>Value F</f></e></c></root> |
> | <a>Value A</a> |
> | <b>Value B</b> |
> | <c><d>Value D</d><e><f>Value F</f></e></c> |
> | <d>Value D</d> |
> | <e><f>Value F</f></e> |
> | <f>Value F</f> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd9ccca1ce53ab85f6e36be16e142b75)*